# Proper lodash method

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an objected named `slip`, this object contains a property `active` which the attr is `'1'`, when the `slip` object is not selected the property `active` has an attr `'0'`.

I have a function that I need to apply only when the property `active` has the attr `'0'`. I want to know which is the best Lodash method to use here in this case

```
var applyStraightWin = function(slip, amount) {
      var moneyLine = _.result(_.find(slip.lines, {isSelected: '1'}), 'moneyLine');
      _.filter(slip.active, function(pickActive) {
        if (pickActive == '1') {
          _.assign(slip, {
            win: amount,
            risk: RiskWinCalculations.calculateStraightBet(amount, parseFloat(moneyLine, 10), false),
            riskSelected: false,
            winSelected: true
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

that `_.filter` method is doind what I want, is taking out the `slip.active != 0`. But, from the background, is there something better to use than the `_.filter` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] is there something better to use than the `_.filter` method

Absolutely: not using it is much better.

```
var moneyLine = _.result(_.find(slip.lines, {isSelected: '1'}), 'moneyLine');
if (slip.active == '1') {
   _.assign(slip, {
     win: amount,
     risk: RiskWinCalculations.calculateStraightBet(amount, parseFloat(moneyLine, 10), false),
     riskSelected: false,
     winSelected: true
   });
}
```

---

The purpose of `_.filter` is to select a subset of a collection. It is not the right function to use if you want to test whether a property has a specific value.

Comment: nope, that is not the right answer, there is like around 5 items which contains this ```slip.active```, in those 5 items if I want I can deactivate one. If I do what you said, than the function will not work. That's why I need iterate over the ones that are ```slip.active == '0'```, got it ? I need to iterate because it is a collection!

Comment: But you are iterating over `slip.active`. Are you saying `slip.active` is a collection of five items? You said `slip` is an object with a property `active` which is either `1` or `0`. Where exactly is the collection?

Comment: I tried the way you said, bro. And couldn't put it to work. I need to use filter, or something similar. I was just asking which method is better to don't include the ones with slip.active == `0`, sorry if I confused you

Comment: I guess you have to provide a better, more complete example. If `slip` is a single object like you say, and `slip.active` is a number or string, it does not make sense to call `_.filter` on `slip` or `slip.active`.

Comment: Based on your description, this is what I expect `slip` to be (in which case my answer works just fine): http://jsfiddle.net/tnx6n8zn/

Comment: ```slip``` is an object I am passing as a param. at the end depending on what I choose I can have 5 ```slip``` objects in the same scope, all of those with the prop active. If I do what you said, and there is one ```slip.active == 0``` and 4 ```slip.active == 1```, then the function will not be called due to the ```== 0```, so, what about the other 4 ```slip.active == 1```?

Comment: *"then the function will not be called due to the == 0, so, what about the other 4 slip.active == 1?"* Uhm no. What's inside the function doesn't impact how often the function is called. How/when/where are you calling it? See, I changed the order and the function is still running twice: http://jsfiddle.net/supf4yus/ . You really should just post a **complete** example which demonstrates the problem.